# forward value from action to view to action in mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I have a scenario where i want one value "tab" to be taken from one action to its view and then from view to another action. I have put the tab value in viewdata to be accessed in view.
Please suggest how do i access this "tab" value in view and then forward it to the action "Authenticate".

I am working on mvc3 2010. Below is my code:

```
    public ActionResult Index(string tab)
    {
        try
        {
            ViewData["tab"] = tab;
            return View("Authorize");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return View("EmptySearch");
        }
    }



@using (Html.BeginForm("Authenticate", "Authorization"))
{
<div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>User Information</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.Label("Password")

            @Html.TextBox("password")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.password)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </p>

    </fieldset>
</div>
}


    [AcceptVerbs("POST")]
    public ActionResult Authenticate(FormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {
            string password = collection["password"];

            password = password.Trim();

            //ViewData["BatchNumber"] = password;

            //dynamicsContext.CommandTimeout = 180;

            //List<BatchMember> batchMemberList =
              //  Queries.compiledBatchQuery(dynamicsContext, password).ToList<BatchMember>();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "GreatPlains");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return View("EmptySearch");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep it in a `Hidden` field in your Form and it will be available in your Post action method

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Authenticate", "Authorization"))
{
<div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>User Information</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.Label("Password")
            @Html.TextBox("password")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.password)
        </div>
        <p>
            @Html.Hidden("Tab", ViewData["tab"])
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </p>

    </fieldset>
</div>
}
```

And in your `HttpPOST` Action method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Authenticate(FormCollection collection)
{
  var tabValue=collection["Tab"]
  //remaining code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use TempData, Session or cookie, or you can add the value of tab as a hidden field in your form and keep using ViewData.

Comment: could you tell me how i can add the value to the hidden field in form?